# android multiple button in single tablerow

Tags: android, tags, tablerow

I am trying to generate the tags by adding button to table row and gridview but the buttons   are not wrapping using tablerow.

xml code :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/l"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    >
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
 <com.manishkpr.androidtagsexample.CustomGrid
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="120dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
   <TableLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:shrinkColumns="0"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tags"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
        <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
         <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
          <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
           <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
            <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
             <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
              <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
               <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
                <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
  </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

In the screen shoot you can see top layout is gridview and bottom layout is a tablrow

table row has 10 button but you can see it is showing me 5
what i want similar to the gridview as shown on screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Make two table rows for tablelayout or Try using weight

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/l"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:shrinkColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tags1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```